# IntelliJ: how to open files in an existing IntelliJ from the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, intellij-idea

I always have an IntelliJ running. Sometimes I want to open a file from outside IntelliJ. I can drag and drop a file to IntelliJ if am in the Finder, but if I am on the command line on OS X, how can I instruct IntelliJ to open a certain file? I am looking for something similar to the `mate` command provided by TextMate.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It's actually already implemented in the **linux** and **OS X** version of **IntelliJ IDEA**.

```
Tools > Create Command-line Launcher...
```

Not sure it's available for windows.

Comment: It's also available in the OS X version of the Ultimate Edition.

Comment: It's available in the Mac OS X Community Edition 13.1

Comment: It's available in the Mac OS X Community Edition 14.1.5 as well.

Comment: It's available in Mac OS X Ultimate Edition 15.0.3.

Comment: What if you don't want to keep the terminal open while its running ?

Comment: The command it creates for IntelliJ IDEA is `idea`. Other versions have different names: `pstorm`, `wstorm`, and so on.

Comment: It might help to create an Alias in your ~/.bash_profile like this: `alias ij="/usr/local/bin/idea --line 1"`. Then you can open any file with `ij file.txt`

Comment: It works, but has problems with special file names (I have file names with a # sign in them... yeah it's unusual)

Comment: In case that existing command line not working, you may just have to go through that process again to update it. It happened to me: the old command line is not working after upgrade intellij. Got to create that again and said yes when prompting for overwrite.

Answer (score 40):

Edit your `~/.bash_profile` adding the following, changing the path to version of IntelliJ you'd like to use:

```
alias "ij=open -a /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 9.0.2.app"
```

Then from the command line, open files with `ij your-file.txt`.

Comment: Or, so you can move IntelliJ later: open -b com.jetbrains.intellij

Comment: @Nicholas Riley, with your suggestion I get: `LSGetApplicationForInfo() failed with error -10814 while trying to determine the application with bundle identifier com.jetbrains.intellij`

Comment: Maybe a later version of IntelliJ has a different bundle ID?  I'm still on 9.0, which uses com.jetbrains.intellij.  You can look in its Info.plist.

Comment: Just for completeness. IJ 12 CE has bundle identifier of `com.jetbrains.intellij.ce`

Comment: `alias ij='open -a "IntelliJ IDEA"'` or `alias ij='open -a "IntelliJ IDEA CE"'` also works ; )

Answer (score 8):

If you want to open file from internel terminal in idea, using following command and press `CTRL+ENTER`:

```sh
open path/of/your/file
```

absolute path and relative path are all supported.

Comment: As of 2022, this should be the Accepted Answer, IMO.

Comment: Agreed! Though on macOS (Cmd+Enter), it leaves an "o" hanging in the terminal for some reason. But it's not big deal : )

Comment: Bump! Spent too much time trying to create an executable wrapper around `open`. This is much easier.

Answer (score 3):

`idea` is the command you are looking for.

At least if you install "IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate", it will create the command `idea` by default in `/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: I tried running `idea filename` and got "command not found". Is that what you meant?

Comment: Thanks! This was the correct answer, Working on Windows from WSL & Terminal :)