# IntelliJ: Ubuntu/linux how to open file with IntelliJ from shell

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

Following this question, it seems that it is possible to open a file from the shell with IntelliJ on MAC.

[IntelliJ: how to open files in an existing IntelliJ from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695820/intellij-how-to-open-files-in-an-existing-intellij-from-the-command-line)

Is there anything something similar for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can associate the files with `IDEA_DIR/bin/idea.sh` file. Or even better, use `Tools` | **Create Command-line Launcher...**

Then you can open files in IDEA using the following command:
`idea FileName.java`

Comment: Thx. In Idea 10 the Create Command-Line Launcher is under File menu.