# Custom Launcher for IntelliJ IDEA in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

I tried it according to the instruction given this link: http://nufailm.blogspot.com/2012/05/custom-launcher-for-intellij-idea-in.html
My version is 13. Therefore I tried instructions for newer versions. It creates a launch icon as shown in snapshot. But problem is it's not working.

Comment: What happens if you run the `Exec` String from the `idea.desktop` in a terminal.

Comment: When you start the application from the shell once you can find a menu option to automatically create such an .desktop file aka. launcher entry.

Comment: Did you try "tools>create desktop entry", in the idea?

Comment: see also [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887286/intellij-ubuntu-linux-how-to-open-file-with-intellij-from-shell) can be useful

Comment: I tried "tools>create desktop entry" then it creates launcher but it does not work.

Answer (score 4):

command for your luncher must be:

```
"/path_to_your_IJ/idea.sh" %f
```

it is worth to mention that IJ can create for You such luncher (see main menu and then Tools -> Create Desktop Entry).

Comment: Normally I use "/path_to_your_IJ/idea.sh" to run IJ. It works fine. I tried "tools->create desktop entry" then it creates launcher but it does not work.

Comment: It means it does not launch IJ IDEA. Actually nothing happens when I click on it.

Comment: Same for me. I click the new icon and nothing happens. Can you please explain the hard coded command "/path_to_your_IJ/idea.sh" %f and where it should be? I'm running 15.04

Comment: You can put IJ anywhere and it should work. Could you add more description? Maybe it is worth to try to run your command from terminal and then see what happens. It should run IJ.