# IntellijIdea 13: use terminal window to open file in the IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal

IntellijIDEA 13 has an embedded shell in a terminal window. That's nice.

Is it possible to open a file from within this terminal window in the IDE for editing?

**Update:**

What I want is an alternative way to open a file for editing from **inside** the IDE.

Instead of using the "Open File..." dialog I want to open a file using IDEA's **built in** terminal window which I now use a lot to run other commands as well.

IDEA's "Go to anything" dialog is another alternative but it only works for files within my project.

**Update 2**

A *good enough* solution has been posted here [IntelliJ: how to open files in an existing IntelliJ from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695820/intellij-how-to-open-files-in-an-existing-intellij-from-the-command-line):

`$ open -b com.jetbrains.Intellij README.md`

opens the file README.md in the current running IDE. It works from the embedded terminal window as well as any other Terminal emulator you are using.

Comment: The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21389004/950708).

Comment: As andruso points out - the answer is built in to intellij, and it is to open Tools > Create Cammand-line Launcher...

Answer (score 1):

Since you do want to open some files with their native application and execute commands as is, you can't reconfigure IntelliJ to open everything within itself. You can however use a batch script to send  a file to IntelliJ. Save this batch somewhere in your path and you'll be able to run this from terminal and having the file opened in IntelliJ:

> idea file.txt

Idea.bat example:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal
SET IJ_PATH="c:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.0.1\bin\idea64.exe"

IF [%1]==[] (
echo usage: %0 file_name
exit /B -1
)
IF NOT EXIST %1 (
echo %1 does not exist
exit /B -2
)

%IJ_PATH% "%~f1"
```

Comment: More things that you can do with IntelliJ from command line - [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/working-with-intellij-idea-features-from-command-line.html)

Comment: Thank you Vic for your answer but it's not what I want. I updated the description.